# Javascript delay execution for 1 hour each day for a month

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Last Edit (hopefully): Inoring the larger problem, if someone could answer "why doesn't the sleep function in the code below provide an hour pause in execution?". A better understanding of that could help.

I want to trigger a js function, running in a chrome extension, that will run constantly for 1 month straight, but pause it's execution for 1 hour between 8:15am and 9:15am.

Here's what I'm trying, but the delay from sleep() isn't happening.

```
function(){ //triggered on button press, one verrryyyyyyy long process
    function sleep(miliseconds) {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
        }
     }

    var data_array = ["fake_data1", "fake_data2", /*...*/ "fake_data923421"];
    for (let i=0; i<data_array.length; i++){
        var today = new Date();
        var hours = today.getHours();
        var minutes = today.getMinutes();
        if(hours >= 8 && minutes >= 15){
            sleep(3600000);
        }
        //do things if it's not 8:15-9:15am
        setTimeout(function() {
            //things here happen as expected with setTimeout delay
            //so far haven't been able to use setTimeout sometimes, but not every time
            //hence the sleep() function (also from SO, sorry no credits posted)
        }, (i+1)*10000);
    }
});
```

Disclaimers:
 - Very open to alternative methods of accomplishing this.
 - There are valid reasons for it to be written in JS, and to run constantly for a month straight.
 - No users will be on the page/locking the UI up is irrelevant

Bonus Points - this is in a chrome extension, if there's a way I can store the data not in an array, and mark each value after it's gone through so if this does have to be stopped, restarting the execution wouldn't force the script back to "fake_data1" - that'd be great. I know I could store in a DB, make my own web service, and call it to do that. Would rather avoid that though, looking for quick and easy as this is more likely than not a one off, non-production, never to be used again code.

Comment: It's unclear what the ultimate goal is so I don't know what to suggest other than setTimeout and/or [chrome.alarms API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms). What's clear is that you're just blocking your extension's JS thread using a loop, and usually it means you're coming from some multi-threaded language like Python, but JS is single-threaded so such an approach doesn't usually make sense.

Comment: Thanks, looking at chrome.alarms but not sure it's what I need. How would you conditionally trigger a setTimeout() inside a loop to delay the execution as I'm attempting?

Comment: I'm still in the dark so I can only randomly suggest using *async/await syntax* and do something like doSomething(); await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3600e3)); doSomething(); and  so on.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever this may help... I still can't comprehend why the sleep function above wasn't working for me, but I modified it with a do-while loop and it's been running as expected.

```
function sleep(miliseconds) {
   var d = new Date();
   var d2 = null;
   do { d2 = new Date(); }
   while(d2-d < miliseconds);
}
```